How to hide scrollbar track (with no overflow)
Problem
This scrollbar track appears all on pages whenever user reloads the page. It is not there initially.
It's strange considering that there's no overflow (hence the lack of a scrollbar) and yet a scrollbar track appears.
Any idea why this is appearing and how to get rid of it?
No scrollbar track (initial load)

Scrollbar track (after user reloads page)

Attempted solutions
I've tried to apply overflow-x: hidden to the parent element (top container) which does not get rid of the track.
I have also gotten rid of components one by one to see if one of them is causing the overflow. None of the components were causing the overflow.
I have tried this method to see which element is causing the overflow, yet there are none
* { outline: 1px solid red; }


The right scrollbar may be the cause.
When connecting to the screen, it is recommended to adjust the entire html and body by the width of the scroll bar on the right.
In the case of MacBooks, since the touchpad is used more, the scrollbar may appear only when operating, or the scrollbar may always be exposed when the Bluetooth mouse is connected.
I can't answer all cases, but I recommend you to adjust regarding the scrollbar on the right side mentioned above.
It may not be an exact answer, but I hope it will help you improve your discomfort.
